Is there any reason why only the Time Stone couldn’t be physically touched?
In MCU, Thanos has been shown physically holding the mind, soul, power and space stones. e.g.

But, in the case of the Time Stone, it’s different.

Why is the Time Stone floating between fingers? Why doesn’t it touch the fingers?
I am looking for both in-universe and out-of-universe reasons.

I dont think any of the stones can be touched directly (like the end of Guardians of the Galaxy) without doing severe damage, we see what happens.  The only one powerful enough to touch them was Thanos, and even then he only held them for a brief time before putting them into the glove.

Or when they were in the collectors display room, his maid/slave took ahold of one and exploded.

For your comment for why it is not touching Dr Strange or the Masters fingers I took it as they were using magic to hold it there so as not to touch it directly.  Though in the pic for Thanos it is doing the same, so maybe there is something with this stone?

No official/canonical answer. There are theories/speculations such as the time stone represents "time" itself, and it is less tangible and complex than other stones. The other stones usually have a direct or more physical impact, unlike the time stone. It was asked and answered on Movies StackExchange also: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101270/cant-the-time-stone-be-touched-with-bare-hands
